# Way to select rows which fall on a specific day?

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there a way in MySQL to select rows which fall on a specific day, as in Mondays, using a date column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL [DAYOFWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function.

E.g. to select Mondays:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE DAYOFWEEK(bar) = 2
```

Comment: This will probably result in this query turning into a full table scan, as the db will need to run dayofweek() on all rows before it knows which of them match the condition.  Consider storing the day of the week explicitly in another column if this table is big.

Answer (score 2):

Look up the DAYOFWEEK() function [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) in the MySQL Online Docs

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a specific Week Day Name, yes there is:

In mysql you can use **DAYOFWEEK()** - [check the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

In PHP you can use getdate() and for example do:

$date = getdate();
$weekday = $date[weekday]; - [check the manual](http://www.php.net/getdate)